# Como individualizar as consultas do banco de dados com PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, select

Olá, bom dia. Tenho o seguinte problema:

Quero tratar a saída do SQL usando o PHP, exibindo os valores de forma individual e personalizada.

Por exemplo, tenho um banco de dados com os valores

```
Tomate | Cebola | Milho    
   2        4       1
```

Eu gostaria de fazer algo com PHP desse gênero

```
<?php 
  $conn = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "banco");
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela";
  $query = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
  /*não sei como "transformaria" o resultado das consultas 
  em variaveis individuais*/
  echo "Você tem $x Tomate(s), $y Cebola(s) e $z Milho(s)";
?>
```

Como posso fazer o que preciso???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu recomendaria você utilizar algo como PDO, já que parece estar utilizando PHP puro, ficaria algo assim:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "usuario";
$password = "senha";
$dbname = "banco";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela");
  $stmt->execute();

  $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
  foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo 'tomate: ' . $result['tomate'];
    echo 'cebola: ' . $result['cebola'];
    echo 'milho: ' . $result['milho'];
  }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

Recomendo a leitura da documentação do [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Obrigado, amigo. Também gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de fazer isso utilizando jQuery e ajax, para tornar as coisas dinâmicas.

Comment: Tem sim, você joga os dados via ajax para um arquivo php de script que executa a query, para o receber dados seria a mesma ideia, dá uma olhada nesse post http://programmerblog.net/php-pdo-ajax-tutorial-example/

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!!!!!!!!!